# Enterprise Cobol 5.2 Debugger Linenumbers exceeded

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos

I have the "wonderful" task of maintaining a legacy program that I didn't write. The Cobol program runs in a z/OS 2.2 environment and is compiled with IBM Enterprise Cobol 5.2. For debugging I would like to compile the program with the option *CBL LIST, TEST (EJPD, SOURCE)*. Unfortunately, my source code has more than 999999 lines, so there is an error when compiling. 
Is there a way to circumvent the limitation of the number of lines or is there only a way to split the program?

Comment: I know it's common practice to maintain code that you didn't write yourself. I was very annoyed and frustrated when I asked the questions. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

The 999999 limit on number of lines has been present since at least VS COBOL II, released in the mid-1980s. It's [also present](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=appendixes-compiler-limits) in Enterprise COBOL 6.3, the latest version prior to the compiler as of this update.

Perhaps someone is having you on, presenting you with uncompilable source.  This is a compiler limit, and as @SaggingRufus has indicated, the solution would be to break the program up into multiple modules.

I would contend that a million+ lines of source code is incomprehensible.

Other mechanisms available to you include evaluating the code, looking for statements that span multiple lines for no good reason...

```
MOVE
A
TO
B
```

...is just silly.

As an aside, maintaining code you didn't write is part of the job.  It used to be normal to put the new employees through a period of maintaining the existing code base to get them familiar with shop standards, etc.

Comment: It seems this limit is there to stay, at least it's still in EC V6.2

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the JES version, I believe you can you the `WARNING` parameter which would look something like this

```
//JOB10 JOB 1234,ME,LINES=(999999,WARNING)
```

This tells the system to continue even if the line limit is hit and only issue a warning.

Alternatively, you could output this compile listing to a file rather than a SYSOUT. Then the line limit would not apply

Also keep in a mind the having that many line in the JES spool is not a good thing, so I would recommend going the file route.

Comment: The JCL option you mention affects the amount of job output. My problem is not the amount of job output but that the compiler with `CBL LIST, TEST (EJPD, SOURCE)` apparently does not process more than 999999 lines of source code....

Comment: If that's the case, then you will need to go to through the logic and find out what can be placed into another and call that program. Either that, or there is potentially a compiler update that will remedy the solution

Comment: Thank you very much. I was afraid that only this solution would remain....

Comment: Wait a bit though, there are people active in the SO mainframe community with MUCH more knowledge than I. They may have a solution.